# How to get SVG background image to bottom of container?

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to use a SVG as a background-image on a pseudo element. The image isn't as tall as the container so I want to position at the bottom of the container and have the background color take up the top, making it look seamless. I can get the image to the bottom of the container if I use negative margins but I'm trying to keep it responsive and that doesn't work.
How do I get the SVG to stay at the bottom?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.left-half {
  position: relative;
  background: #ff9e2c;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.right-half {
  background: #b6701e;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.left-half::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/svg/SVG/mountMckinley.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="left-half">
    <article>
      <h1>Left Half</h1>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="right-half">
    <article>
      <h1 class="font">William Cunningham</h1>
      <p>Web Design, Teaching, Photography, & Fly-Fishing</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

```css
html, body, section, div {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #b6701e;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  padding: 1rem;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.left-half {
  position: relative;
  background: #ff9e2c;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.right-half {
  background: #b6701e;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.left-half::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://williamcunningham.me/mountMckinley.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="left-half">
    <article>
      <h1>Left Half</h1>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="right-half">
    <article>
      <h1 class="font">Right Half</h1>
      
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding "bottom" to your background element should do it:

```
background: url(https://williamcunningham.me/mountMckinley.svg) no-repeat bottom;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `position: absolute; bottom:0;` doesnt work is because you give it an `height: 100%;` which makes the element with the background image take the height of the full block.

You just have to add `background-position: bottom;` to the `.left-half::after {}` so it allways stays at the bottom.

```css
html, body, section, div {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px #b6701e;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  padding: 1rem;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.left-half {
  position: relative;
  background: #ff9e2c;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.right-half {
  background: #b6701e;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.left-half::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://williamcunningham.me/mountMckinley.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="left-half">
    <article>
      <h1>Left Half</h1>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="right-half">
    <article>
      <h1 class="font">Right Half</h1>
      
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation as to why it was happening.